# R class not generating ids

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two layout files, one is for the main activity and the other XML file is for the alyout of my custom list view. I would like to access the IDs of the views in my layout file but in the R class there are only IDs from the main activity XML File. I would like to know how I can add the IDs to the R Class or else access them by any other means.

Thanks and sorry if its a lame question but I am fairly new to android.

This is the main activity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ListView 
      android:id="@+id/list1"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView android:id="@+id/imgSports"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/rowTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: how are you planning to use those layouts? by creating activities or fragments?

Comment: These ids should be automatically generated. Lets try to clean project or Fix project properties.

Comment: Are you adding the + sign to the id keyword? bad -> android:id="@id/invalidId"    good-> android:id="@+id/validId"

Comment: @VJD one of the layout file is for the actual activity screen where the list view is, the other layout file is for the layout of the row of the listview

Answer (score 1):

When you create an activity it will create its default layout xml.
As far as i understand your problem, you want the same activity to display a list.
If that is the case, i suggest you try to put your design in that default activity layout, that will create id in R.
Also i would suggest to go and refer basic android tutorial provided on android developers site under heading "build your first app" that will help.you understand this.